# Пустая страница при npm run build (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

Приложение на **ReactJS** после **npm run build** открывается просто пустая страница.

лог **npm run build**

```
> react-ui@0.1.0 build C:\Users\Администратор\myapp
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  36.09 KB  build\static\js\main.8b5123b1.js
  668 B     build\static\css\main.61c924d4.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  serve -s build
```

Comment: у меня то же самое. serve -s build работает но как запустить на хостинге? все файлы типа /js/main.8b5123b1.js подключаются, но страница пустая

Answer (score 1):

`npm run build`, если мне не изменяет память, генерирует в директорию `dist` весь контент (index.html, css, js, images etc).

Если вы пытаетесь просто открыть `index.html` в браузере (без использования локального/внешнего сервера: nginx/apache/express/karma), то будет отображаться пустая страница, а в консоли будет отображаться ошибка, что страница не может найти ресурсы (которые, в большинстве случаев, имеют абсолютные пути от корня сайта, т.е. `/js/main.8b5123b1.js`).

Попробуйте сделать то, что предлагается вам сделать в логе - запустите: `serve -s build`, чтобы запустить локальный сервер.

P.S. Ещё было бы не плохо чуть подробнее рассказать о приложении, которое вы запускаете. Возможно, даже кинуть ссылку на него (если оно находится в публичном доступе), чтобы мы понимали, какая конфигурация на нём настроена.